# TensorFlow operator overloading

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

What is the difference between

```
   tf.add(x, y)
```

and

```
   x + y
```

in TensorFlow? What would be different in your computation graph when you construct your graph with `+` instead of `tf.add()`?

More generally, are  `+` or other operations overloaded for tensors?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

If at least one of `x` or `y` is a [`tf.Tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/0.6.0/api_docs/python/framework.html#Tensor) object, the expressions `tf.add(x, y)` and `x + y` are equivalent. The main reason you might use `tf.add()` is to specify an explicit [`name`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/0.6.0/api_docs/python/math_ops.html#add) keyword argument for the created op, which is not possible with the overloaded operator version.

Note that if neither `x` nor `y` is a `tf.Tensor`—for example if they are NumPy arrays—then `x + y` will not create a TensorFlow op. `tf.add()` always creates a TensorFlow op and converts its arguments to `tf.Tensor` objects. Therefore, if you are writing a library function that might accept both tensors and NumPy arrays, you might prefer to use `tf.add()`.

The following operators are overloaded in the TensorFlow Python API:

- `__neg__` (unary `-`)
- `__abs__` (`abs()`)
- `__invert__` (unary `~`)
- `__add__` (binary `+`)
- `__sub__` (binary `-`)
- `__mul__` (binary elementwise `*`)
- `__div__` (binary `/` in Python 2)
- `__floordiv__` (binary `//` in Python 3)
- `__truediv__` (binary `/` in Python 3)
- `__mod__` (binary `%`)
- `__pow__` (binary `**`)
- `__and__` (binary `&`)
- `__or__` (binary `|`)
- `__xor__` (binary `^`)
- `__lt__` (binary `<`)
- `__le__` (binary `<=`)
- `__gt__` (binary `>`)
- `__ge__` (binary `>=`)

Please note, `__eq__` ( binary `==` ) is **not** overloaded. `x == y` will simply return a Python boolean whether `x` and `y` refer to the same tensor. You need to use [`tf.equal()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/equal) explicitly to check for element-wise equality. Same goes for not equal, `__ne__` ( binary `!=` ).

Comment: what if we want `==` operator on tensor scalar comparation?

Comment: @K.Wanter you need to use `tf.equal()`. `==` and `!=` are not overloaded. (Or `( x <= y ) & ( y <= x )` if you feel rebellious. :) )

Comment: One thing to add is that you can also overload `tf.matmul()` with `@` like in numpy.

Comment: it doesn't appear to be this simple re `==`. For example, `tf.constant([0]) == tf.constant([0])` is a `tf.Tensor` containing `[True]`, at least in tf2. Appears eager execution has an effect

Answer (score 1):

Mrry nicely explained that there is no real difference. I will just add when using `tf.add` is beneficial.

[tf.add](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/add) has one important parameter which is `name`. It allows you to name the operation in a graph which will be visible in tensorboard. So my rule of thumb, if it will be beneficial to name an operation in tensorboard, I use `tf.` equivalent, otherwise I go for brevity and use overloaded version.