# In tensorflow what is the difference between tf.add and operator (+)?

Tags: tensorflow

In tensorflow tutorials, I see both codes like `tf.add(tf.matmul(X, W), b)` and `tf.matmul(X, W) + b`, what is the difference between using the math function `tf.add()`, `tf.assign()`, etc and the operators `+` and `=`, etc, in precision or other aspects?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TensorFlow operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35094899/tensorflow-operator-overloading)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

There's no difference in precision between `a+b` and `tf.add(a, b)`. The former translates to `a.__add__(b)` which gets mapped to `tf.add` by means of [following line](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/c43a32d5d0929170a057862e2cd0b59308421444/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py#L845) in math_ops.py

`_OverrideBinaryOperatorHelper(gen_math_ops.add, "add")`

The only difference is that node name in the underlying Graph is `add` instead of `Add`. You can generally compare things by looking at the underlying Graph representation like this

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
dtype = tf.int32
a = tf.placeholder(dtype)
b = tf.placeholder(dtype)
c = a+b
print(tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def())
```

You could also see this directly by inspecting the `__add__` method. There's an extra level of indirection because it's a closure, but you can get the underlying function as follows

```
real_function = tf.Tensor.__add__.im_func.func_closure[0].cell_contents
print(real_function.__module__ + "." + real_function.__name__)
print(tf.add.__module__ + "." + tf.add.__name__)
```

And you'll see output below which means that they call same underlying function

```
tensorflow.python.ops.gen_math_ops.add
tensorflow.python.ops.gen_math_ops.add
```

You can see from `tf.Tensor.OVERLOADABLE_OPERATORS` that following Python special methods are potentially overloaded by appropriate TensorFlow versions

```
{'__abs__',
 '__add__',
 '__and__',
 '__div__',
 '__floordiv__',
 '__ge__',
 '__getitem__',
 '__gt__',
 '__invert__',
 '__le__',
 '__lt__',
 '__mod__',
 '__mul__',
 '__neg__',
 '__or__',
 '__pow__',
 '__radd__',
 '__rand__',
 '__rdiv__',
 '__rfloordiv__',
 '__rmod__',
 '__rmul__',
 '__ror__',
 '__rpow__',
 '__rsub__',
 '__rtruediv__',
 '__rxor__',
 '__sub__',
 '__truediv__',
 '__xor__'}
```

Those methods are described in [Python reference 3.3.7](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types): emulating numeric types. Note that Python data model does not provide a way to overload assignment operator `=` so assignment always uses native Python implementation.

Comment: So why these tensorflow methods are defined at all?

Comment: @Hossein Because we at Google love being extra.

Answer (score 11):

Yaroslav nicely explained that there is no real difference. I will just add when using `tf.add` is beneficial.

[tf.add](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/add) has one important parameter which is `name`. It allows you to name the operation in a graph which will be visible in tensorboard. So my rule of thumb, if it will be beneficial to name an operation in tensorboard, I use `tf.` equivalent, otherwise I go for brevity and use overloaded version.

Answer (score -4):

```
a = [1,1,1,1]
b = [1,1,1,1]
w = tf.add(a, b)


with tf.Session() as sess:
    p = sess.run(w)
    print(p)

a+b
```

Now, the value of `p` printed will be `[2,2,2,2]` and simple `a+b` printed will be `[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]`.