# Tensorflow Variables and Ops vs. Python Equivalents

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm new to Tensorflow.

- Is it necessary to use tensorflow's function, such as using `tf.constant()` to replace `int32`, `float32` or else?
- Also during computation, using `tf.mul()` instead of normal Python multiplication `*`?
- Also the print function `tf.Print()` instead of `print()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/api_docs/python/framework.md#class-tftensor-tensor),

> A Tensor is a symbolic handle to one of the outputs of an Operation. It does not hold the values of that operation's output, but instead provides a means of computing those values in a TensorFlow Session

So tensor variables aren't like python variables. Rather they specify the relationship between operations in the [computational graph](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/resources/faq.html#building-a-tensorflow-graph). The python variables that you use to describe the graph are for the programmer's convenience, but it might be easier to think about the python variables and the tensor variables as being in parallel namespaces. This example may help:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
  a = tf.constant([1, 2, 3])
  b = tf.Variable([])
  b = 2 * a
  sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
  print(b) # Tensor("mul:0", shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
  print(b.eval()) # [2, 4, 6]
  b = tf.Print(b, [b])  # [2, 4, 6] (at the command line)
```

From this you can see:

- `print(b)` returns information about the operation that 'b' refers to as well as the variable shape and data type, but not the value.
- `b.eval()` (or `sess.run(b)`) returns the value of `b` as a numpy array which can be printed by a python `print()`
- `tf.Print()` allows you to see the value of `b` during graph execution.

Note that the syntax of `tf.Print()` might seem a little strange to a newbie. As described in the documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops.html#Print), `tf.Print()` is an identity operation that only has the side effect of printing to the command line. The first parameter is just passed through. The second parameter is the list of tensors that are printed and can be different than the first parameter. Also note that in order for `tf.Print()` to do something, a variable used in a subsequent call to `sess.run()` needs to be dependent on the tensor output by `tf.Print()`, otherwise this portion of the graph will not be executed.

Finally with respect to math ops such as `tf.mul()` vs `*` many of the normal python ops are overloaded with the equivalent tensorflow ops, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37901852/5587428).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think it is better to do the computation in a Tensorflow's way: build graph and compute it in the session. Also, I just guess there might be some optimization on tensor's calculation such as in some case, using `tf.mul` might be better than normal python multiplication.

Comment: Another thing I'm considering is that, if I need use [**TensorBoard**](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/how_tos/summaries_and_tensorboard/index.html) to visualize the graph, while it support non-tensorflow operation like numpy's operation or normal python's operation? I'm working on a small network and I'll try it later. Could you tell me is there any good habits to coding with Tensorflow? Like setting default `tf.Session` to use `operation.eval()`, instead of `with tf.Session as sess:`. Since there are many ways to build a graph and run the graph, is there some certain you'd prefer?

Comment: I think that each person needs to develop their own coding style. I suggest you look at various tensorflow routines on github and if you like one person's style try to follow it. In any case, if you have specific problems or questions, just post them to this forum. The TF community here seems very responsive.

Answer (score 1):

Because tensorflow is built upon a computation graph. When you construct the graph in python, you are just building is a description of computations (not actually doing the computation). To compute anything, a graph must be launched in a Session. So it's best to do the computation with the tensorflow ops.

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/get_started/basic_usage.html