# What are the operations allowed in tensorflow loss function definition?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I learned that we need to use `tf.OPERATIONS` to define the computation graph, but I found sometimes, using `+` or `=` are just fine, without using `tf.add` or `tf.assign` see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37900780/in-tensorflow-what-is-the-difference-between-tf-add-and-operator).

My question is that what are the operations allowed in tensorflow loss function definition without using "tf.OPERATIONS". In other words, other than `+` and `=` what else? can we use for example `*`, or `^2` on variables?

PS: I just do not understand why `x*x` is ok but `x^2` is not ...