# Is 'tensorflow.negative' always the same as operator "-"?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I see some tensorflow functions which do element-wise operations: `reduce_sum`, `add`, `negative`, etc.

e.g. this code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
distance = tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(tf.add(xtr, tf.negative(xte))), reduction_indices=1)
```

When I try using the following code instead, I found they have the same effect:

```
distance = tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(xtr-xte), reduction_indices=1)
```

So I'm wondering:

1, Whether `add`, `negative`, `multiply` can always being replaced by `+`, `-`, `*`? If NOT, can u give me some exceptive examples?

2, Also, how can I list ALL the functions that have corresponding operators?

Comment: I've never seen someone "raise" an example. Reword a bit, please?

Comment: @connectyourcharger thx, I've edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can always replace them with corresponding operator.

Check this question for full list

[In tensorflow what is the difference between tf.add and operator (+)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37900780/in-tensorflow-what-is-the-difference-between-tf-add-and-operator)