# Dot product of two vectors in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, dot-product

I was wondering if there is an easy way to calculate the dot product of two vectors (i.e. 1-d tensors) and return a scalar value in tensorflow.

Given two vectors X=(x1,...,xn) and Y=(y1,...,yn), the dot product is
dot(X,Y) = x1 * y1 + ... + xn * yn

I know that it is possible to achieve this by first broadcasting the vectors X and Y to a 2-d tensor and then using tf.matmul. However, the result is a matrix, and I am after a scalar.

Is there an operator like tf.matmul that is specific to vectors?

Answer (score 33):

One of the easiest way to calculate dot product between two tensors (vector is 1D tensor) is using [`tf.tensordot`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tensordot)

```
a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(5))
b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(5))

dot_a_b = tf.tensordot(a, b, 1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(dot_a_b.eval(feed_dict={a: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], b: [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]}))
# results: 130.0
```

Answer (score 27):

In addition to `tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(x, y))`, you can also do `tf.matmul(x, tf.reshape(y, [-1, 1]))`.

Comment: note that this is the only correct answer if you have a vector with dimensions `(1234,)`

Answer (score 20):

you can use tf.matmul and tf.transpose

```
tf.matmul(x,tf.transpose(y))
```

or

```
tf.matmul(tf.transpose(x),y)
```

depending on the dimensions of x and y

Comment: `matmul` can transpose things for you: e.g. `tf.matmul(a, b, transpose_a=True, transpose_b=False)` you can also transpose b obviously.

Answer (score 4):

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.Variable([1, -2, 3], tf.float32, name='x')
y = tf.Variable([-1, 2, -3], tf.float32, name='y')

dot_product = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(x, y))

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init_op)

dot_product.eval()

Out[46]: -14
```

Here, x and y are both vectors. We can do element wise product and then use tf.reduce_sum to sum the elements of the resulting vector. This solution is easy to read and does not require reshaping.

Interestingly, it does not seem like there is a built in dot product operator in the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/math_ops/).

Note that you can easily check intermediate steps:

```
In [48]: tf.multiply(x, y).eval()
Out[48]: array([-1, -4, -9], dtype=int32)
```

Answer (score 3):

In newer versions (I think since 0.12), you should be able to do

```
tf.einsum('i,i->', x, y)
```

([Before that](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blame/8532897352ada1d8ecd3ca1dd17aaa869a42d4b8/tensorflow/python/ops/special_math_ops.py#L100), the reduction to a scalar seemed not to be allowed/possible.)

Comment: apparently einsum is slow

Comment: That can happen, it depends on the concrete operation and how well the reduction is optimized. Cf. [opt-einsum](https://github.com/dgasmith/opt_einsum).

Answer (score 2):

You can do tf.mul(x,y), followed by tf.reduce_sum()

Comment: ( it should of course be tf.multiply(x,y) )

Answer (score 2):

### Just use * and reduce_sum

```
ab = tf.reduce_sum(a*b)
```

Take a simple example as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.constant([1,2,3])
b = tf.constant([2,3,4])

print(a.get_shape())
print(b.get_shape())

c = a*b
ab = tf.reduce_sum(c)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(c.eval())
    print(ab.eval())

# output
# (3,)
# (3,)
# [2 6 12]
# 20
```

Comment: regarding the use of '*': https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35094899/tensorflow-operator-overloading/35095052

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with the new docs you can just set the transpose option to true for either the first argument of the dot product or the second argument:

```
tf.matmul(a, b, transpose_a=False, transpose_b=False, adjoint_a=False, adjoint_b=False, a_is_sparse=False, b_is_sparse=False, name=None)
```

leading:

```
tf.matmul(a, b, transpose_a=True, transpose_b=False)
tf.matmul(a, b, transpose_a=False, transpose_b=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume that you have two column vectors

```
u = tf.constant([[2.], [3.]])
v = tf.constant([[5.], [7.]])
```

If you want a 1x1 matrix you can use

```
tf.einsum('ij,ik->jk',x,y)
```

If you are interested in a scalar you can use

```
tf.einsum('ij,ik->',x,y)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(x,y)) if you want the dot product of 2 vectors.**

To be clear, using tf.matmul(x,tf.transpose(y)) won't get you the dot product, even if you add all the elements of the matrix together afterward.

I'm only mentioning this because of how often it comes up in the above answers when it has nothing to do with the question being asked. I'd just make a comment, but don't have the rep to do that.