# what is wrong with my cosine similarity? Tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I want to use cosine similarity in my Neural network, instead of the standard dot product.

I've had a look at the [dot product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40670370/dot-product-of-two-vectors-in-tensorflow) and at the [cosine similarity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43357732/how-to-calculate-the-cosine-similarity-between-two-tensors).

In the example above they use

```python
a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None], name="input_placeholder_a")
b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None], name="input_placeholder_b")
normalize_a = tf.nn.l2_normalize(a,0)        
normalize_b = tf.nn.l2_normalize(b,0)
cos_similarity=tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(normalize_a,normalize_b))
sess=tf.Session()
cos_sim=sess.run(cos_similarity,feed_dict={a:[1,2,3],b:[2,4,6]})
```

However, I tried doing it my own way

```python
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 3], name = 'x') # input has 3 features
w1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [10, 3], name = 'w1') # 10 nodes in the first hidden layer
cos_sim = tf.divide(tf.matmul(x, w1), tf.multiply(tf.norm(x), tf.norm(w1)))
with tf.Session() as sess:
      sess.run(cos_sim, feed_dict = {x = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], w1: np.random.uniform(0,1,size = (10,3) )})
```

Is my way wrong? Also, what is going on in the matrix multiplication? Are we actually multiplying the weights of one node for the inputs of different samples (within one feature)?

Comment: Also, often I get errors of shape with the first method, sometimes with the second

Comment: It thought that `W` had shape (number_nodes, number_features) whereas the input matrix `X` had shape (number_samples, number_features). But clearly then the matrix multiplication does not make sense! So actually instead of WX do we not have WX^T?

Comment: Because I thought we used w_{ij} ^ L where i is the node number in layer L+1, j is the node number in laye L. Thus if we were to do WX then we would multiply all the weights incoming to one node in the hidden layer, with all the samples of ONE feature in X... which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a problem with dimensions in your example, I think `w1` should have a `[3, 10]` shape. But ignoring these minor details, your implementation seems to be correct.

Though, I would suggest an approach closer to the top example, that is using `tf.nn.l2_normalize`, because it guarantees to return the same shape as input, so gives flexibility to choose the dimensions along which to normalize. In addition, [`tf.nn.l2_normalize`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/l2_normalize) provides numerical stability when the denominator is near zero, and is likely to be a bit more efficient.

```
a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 3], name="input_placeholder_a")
b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[3, 10], name="input_placeholder_b")

normalize_a = tf.nn.l2_normalize(a, dim=0)
normalize_b = tf.nn.l2_normalize(b, dim=0)
cos_similarity=tf.matmul(normalize_a, normalize_b)

sess=tf.Session()
cos_sim=sess.run(cos_similarity,feed_dict={
  a: np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]),
  b: np.arange(30).reshape([3, 10])
})
print cos_sim
```

It gives the same result as yours.

Comment: why `dim = 0` ?

Comment: I just made it the same as in the top example. You can set `dim=[0, 1]` to normalize across both dimensions. In general, it's up to you to decide the best directions for normalization

Comment: So does it mean that if we have `a = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])` then it will do:

1) Find the mean across dimension 0: (1+2+3) / 3 = 2 and (4+5+6) / 3 = 5.
2) Find the standard deviation std1 = std({1,2,3}) , std2 = std({4,5,6}).
3) Calculate ([1,2,3] - 2) / std1 and ([4,5,6] - 5) / sd2 ?

Comment: You mix up Gaussian normalization and L2 norm. The latter operates with sum of squares. Here's implementation: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_impl.py#L314

Comment: Oh okay! with `dim = 0` it takes the norm of the "vertical" vector and then divides that vector by its norm!