# MatMul rank error when trying to convert math operations

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, multidimensional-array

I have a script and I am trying to convert my math operations from NumPy operations to TensorFlow operations so it can get faster on GPU. And in my script I end up in a situation that I have an array with shape (260) and need to do matrix multiplication with another array with shape (260), illustrated by:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([2] * 260)
y = np.array([4] * 260)
r = np.matmul(x,y) #np.dot(x,y) also works
print(r) #2080
```

But the same operation in TensorFlow is not possible.

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.Variable([2] * 260)
y = tf.Variable([4] * 260)
r = tf.matmul(x,y)

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.Session()

sess.run(init)
result = sess.run(r)
print(result) # ERRROR
```

The TensorFlow error says:

> ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 1 for 'MatMul' (op:
>   'MatMul') with input shapes: [260], [260].

I have tried to reshape the inputs countless many ways, and none of those have worked, such as: `x = tf.expand_dims(x,1)`.

Comment: Read what `np.matmul` says about handling 1d inputs.  `np.dot` also has special handling of 1d inputs (inner product).  Does the `tensorflow` documentation say anything about handling 1ds?

Comment: No! I could not find anything in the Tensorflow documentation that would explain the behavior on 1-D input, but reading from the numpy documentation, it makes more sense now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since both inputs are 1-dimensional, your matrix multiplication is the inner product,

```
tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(x, y))
```

or

```
tf.tensordot(x, y, 1)
```

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40670370/5085211) for a few alternative ways of calculating the inner product.