# Tensor comparison does not work as expected

Tags: python, tensorflow

I need to write a piece of code to understand if any of a tensor's entries have a specific value "2".

This is the code I'm using for testing:

```
sess = tf.Session()
some_values = tf.constant([1,2,3,4], dtype=tf.int32)
values_equal_two = (some_values == 2 )
print(sess.run(values_equal_two))
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
TypeError: Fetch argument False has invalid type <class 'bool'>, must be a 
string or Tensor. (Can not convert a bool into a Tensor or Operation.)
```

Surprisingly, if I change the == operator to >= like this:

```
sess = tf.Session()
some_values = tf.constant([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=tf.int32)
values_equal_two = (some_values >= 2)
print(sess.run(values_equal_two))
```

it works fine, and returns:

```
[False  True  True  True]
```

I was wondering what the problem might be, or if it's possible to do the same task in another way. Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the `>=` operator works as you expected while `==` doesn't, is because, the `__ge__` python method has been overloaded in the TensorFlow Python API while `__eq__` hasn't (check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35095052/4282745)).

If you want to check for equality, you could use [`tf.equal`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/equal) which supports broadcasting:

```
sess = tf.Session()
some_values = tf.constant([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=tf.int32)
values_equal_two = tf.equal(some_values, 2)
print(sess.run(values_equal_two))
```

prints `[False  True False False]`.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative to check if a single or multiple values exist in a target list.
use [`tf.setdiff1d`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.3/api_docs/python/tf/setdiff1d)

```
 # get the values which are not 2
 diffs,_ = tf.setdiff1d(some_values, tf.convert_to_tensor([2]))
 > print(sess.run(diffs))  # results: array([1, 3, 4], dtype=int32)
 # check if 2 exist in the list some_values
 final_diff, _= tf.setdiff1d(some_values, diffs)
 > print(sess.run(final_diff))  # results: array([2], dtype=int32)
```