# Why does Tensorflow not override __eq__ for Tensors?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

Tensorflow overrides multiple operators for the `Tensor` class, [including `__lt__`, `__ge__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35094899/tensorflow-operator-overloading), etc.

However, the implementation for `__eq__` [seems to be conspicuously absent](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/27767d8e9c1325979cf32ff5b81c10df9006fd57/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py#L1164-L1167):

```py
ops.Tensor._override_operator("__lt__", gen_math_ops.less)
ops.Tensor._override_operator("__le__", gen_math_ops.less_equal)
ops.Tensor._override_operator("__gt__", gen_math_ops.greater)
ops.Tensor._override_operator("__ge__", gen_math_ops.greater_equal)
```

Why does `==` for tensorflow's tensors not behave the same way as for numpy arrays?

Code example:

```
a = tf.constant([1,2])
b = tf.constant([3,4])
a == b
>>> False
a < b
>>> <tf.Tensor 'Less:0' shape=(2,) dtype=bool>
```

With numpy, on the other hand:

```
a = np.asarray([1,2])
b = np.asarray([3, 4])
a == b
>>> array([False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Are you basing the assertion that `__eq__` is not defined solely on those lines? Because I see [other code that handles operator overrides in a generic manner](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/27767d8e9c1325979cf32ff5b81c10df9006fd57/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py#L875-L935) for example.

Comment: `import tensorflow as tf`, then `__eq__ in vars(tf.Tensor)` produces `True`, so it does define the hook. It is defined [directly on the class](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/27767d8e9c1325979cf32ff5b81c10df9006fd57/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py#L489-L491).

Comment: @MartijnPieters No, my observations were based on my code not doing what I expected it to do. The links were produced after some digging. Also, I know that equality of tensors is defined. However, it is non-compliant with `numpy` arrays. I hope the added code clarifies the question.

Comment: **Why** should tensors broadcast when testing for equality? The project clearly made an explicit decision to test for identity instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It is a curious decision in my opinion because other operators work in the Tensor setting just as `numpy` arrays while there do exist methods `tf.less_than`, `tf.greater_equal`, etc. So a conscious decision was made to override `<` and `<=` while not `==` (one is used *forced* to use `tf.equal` there?) Was there something special about `==`, which prevented conformity? If so, I'd like to know.

Comment: Yes, there is something special; I found a github issue that explains why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tensors *do* implement `__eq__`, but [the implementation only tests for identity](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.3.1/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py#L448-L450). I found [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9359), which explains why tensors test for identity, and do not broadcast:

> This may be a complication of fact that tensors can be used as keys in dictionaries, which I believe use `==` to find the matching object with the same hash

The commenter is correct; if `__eq__` was overloaded to broadcast then you could not use tensors as keys in a dictionary. Objects that define a `__hash__` method (required if you want to use such objects as keys in a dictionary), **must** produce the same hash value for two objects that are equal; see the [`__hash__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__):

> The only required property is that objects which compare equal have the same hash value

but broadcasting would produce a 'true' tensor object for objects with different hash values.

(the speculation that `__eq__` would break boolean testing is wrong; boolean testing uses [`__bool__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__), which tensors do implement).

If you need to make element-wise equality tests on tensors, you can use the [`tf.equal()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/equal) and [`tf.not_equal()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/not_equal) functions.

Comment: @musically_ut: well, `__eq__` is defined, explicitly, as an identity test.

Comment: Wow! The design decision of using tensors as keys in the `feed_dict` leads to `__eq__` *not* being defined in the same way as for `numpy` for `tf.Tensors`!

Comment: it doesn't appear to be this straightfoward. For example, tf.constant([0]) == tf.constant([0]) is a tf.Tensor containing [True], at least in tf2. Appears eager execution has an effect