# Tensorflow - Graph is finalized and cannot be modified

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, tensorflow

I am trying to launch a Distributed Tensorflow and get the following error.
My code looks like this:

```
sv = tf.train.Supervisor(is_chief=(task_index == 0), logdir="/tmp/train_logs", init_op=init_op,
                         summary_op=summary_op, saver=saver, global_step=global_step, save_model_secs=600)
with sv.managed_session(server.target) as sess:

step = 0
while not sv.should_stop() and step < nnc.steps:

    mini_batches = random_mini_batches(x_train, y_train, mini_batch_size)

    for mini_batch in mini_batches:
        (batch_x, batch_y) = mini_batch

        _, step = sess.run([train_op, global_step], feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
```

When I get the error it's failed on `random_mini_batches` function.
But I completely don't understand how and why. `random_mini_batches` function is a function written in pure python + numpy without anything related to TensorFlow. `x_train` and `y_train` were not used before.

Here is the error that I get:

```
File "/Users/curr_user/PycharmProjects/curr_project/src/nn.py", line 36, in random_mini_batches
    num_complete_minibatches = int(math.floor(m / mini_batch_size))  # number of mini batches of size mini_batch_size
  File "/Users/curr_user/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 880, in r_binary_op_wrapper
    x = ops.convert_to_tensor(x, dtype=y.dtype.base_dtype, name="x")
  File "/Users/curr_user/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 611, in convert_to_tensor
    as_ref=False)
  File "/Users/curr_user/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 676, in internal_convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "/Users/curr_user/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 121, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "/Users/curr_user/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 106, in constant
    attrs={"value": tensor_value, "dtype": dtype_value}, name=name).outputs[0]
  File "/Users/curr_user/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2582, in create_op
    self._check_not_finalized()
  File "/Users/curr_user/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2290, in _check_not_finalized
    raise RuntimeError("Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.")
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not in your question, but I think that `mini_batch_size` is a constant tensor. Though `random_mini_batches` is in pure python and numpy, [tensorflow overloads](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35094899/712995) lots of operators with tensors, so this line

```
num_complete_minibatches = int(math.floor(m / mini_batch_size))
```

is, in fact, performing a `__div__` operation on a tensor, which forces to convert `m` to a tensor as well. But `tf.train.Supervisor()` forces the graph finalization, i.e. no more nodes can be created, as a result, the conversion fails.

The solution is to make `mini_batch_size` an ordinary constant and make sure no tensors are used inside `random_mini_batches`.