# Do I need to add custom gradients for this op?

Tags: tensorflow, autodiff

I have a convolutional layer, which produces 16 output feature maps, and I want to take these maps and transform them into 4 maps like this:

1. Split 16 feature maps into 4 groups, 4 maps each.
2. Multiply each group by a mask to zero out some values.
3. Add the resulting feature maps in each group to get 4 maps.

Or, I can first multiply all 16 maps by a mask, and then split the result into 4 groups to do reduce_sum on each group. The resulting 4 maps will be used as input to the next convolutional or pooling layer.

Will Tensorflow be able to automatically calculate gradient for this combination of tf.split, tf.multiply, and tf.reduce_sum?

EDIT: here's the series of ops, where `conv` is an output from `tf.layers.conv2d`, and `mask` is a binary numpy array of the same shape as `conv`  (full code is [here](https://gist.github.com/michaelklachko/7584ccf224264a809ec76672950cc274)):

```
conv_masked = mask * conv
conv_grouped = tf.reshape(conv_masked, (batch_size, num_groups, fs*fs, dim, dim))
out = tf.reduce_sum(conv_grouped, axis=2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All tensorflow operations already have the gradient formula implemented. As long as all your operations are tf.operation, you are fine.

Also, as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35094899/tensorflow-operator-overloading), tensorflow overloads basic operations.

```
masked_tensor = tensor * mask
masked_tensor = tf.multiply(tensor, mask)
```

If the elements involved are tensors then the two expressions above are equivalent.

As for the type used for the mask

```
mask = tf.constant(array)
mask = np.array(array)
```

For me, using python 3.6.3 and tensorflow 1.3.0 both generated the same result from the operation. But I found nothing in the documentation that explicitly says that np.arrays are always accepted, so I would avoid it.

One point of notice though is that the mask you are multiplying by should be a non-trainable variable. Otherwise the optimizer will alter your mask.

Comment: I added a code example, please take a look. Right now I simply multiply tensor by mask, with mask being a numpy array. I'm not sure if I should convert it to a tensor, e.g. mask_T = tf.constant(mask)?