# If you use plus sign instead of tf.add, will tensorflow still calculate gradients correctly?

Tags: python, tensorflow

If I have a fairly complex equation for the cost like this:

```
cost = tf.reduce_sum( tf.multiply( y , tf.log(y/abs(yy)))  + \
                      tf.multiply( (1 - y) , tf.log((1-y)/abs(1-yy)) ) )
```

will tensorflow still figure out the correct backpropagation equations for this? In other words, how can I be sure that the gradients are calculated correctly?

Answer (score 5):

As described in this [anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35095052), `__add__` op (and `__mul__` as well btw) are overloaded, therefore

```
cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.add(
    tf.multiply( y , tf.log(y/abs(yy))),
    tf.multiply((1 - y) , tf.log((1-y)/abs(1-yy)))
))
```

is equivalent to

```
cost = tf.reduce_sum(y * tf.log(y/abs(yy))  + (1 - y) * tf.log((1-y)/abs(1-yy)))
```