# How to multiply Keras tensor by scalar?

Tags: keras, tensor

if I have tensors, `v`, `w`, I know you can multiply them together with

```
a = Multiply()([v, w])
```

But what if I want to multiply `v` or `w` by a scalar?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use a `Lambda` layer for any other scalar manipulations

**Scalar Multiplication**:

```
res5 = Lambda(lambda x: x * 3)(res4)
```

**Scalar Addition**:

```
res5 = Lambda(lambda x: x + 4)(res4)
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using tensorflow as your backend, the * operator is supported (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35095052/2336208)).

`a = v * 0.10`