# Tf.where doesn't evaluate

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
t = tf.expand_dims(tf.constant(list(range(9))), axis=1)
tf.where(t == 5).eval()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): WhereOp : Unhandled input dimensions: 0
     [[Node: Where_16 = Where[T=DT_BOOL, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](Where_16/condition)]]
```

What's going on here? The corresponding code in Numpy with np.where works.

Comment: shouldn't you be doing this inside a session scope?

Comment: Does this work for you ? `print( tf.where(tf.equal(t,5)).eval() )`

Comment: Can you post a longer traceback? What happens if you try running with eager execution instead of interactive session?

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you are evaluating `tf.where(False)` since the `==` operator is not overloaded for tensors. (More info e.g. here: [TensorFlow operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35094899/tensorflow-operator-overloading))

Try:

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
t = tf.expand_dims(tf.constant(list(range(9))), axis=1)
tf.where(tf.equal(t, 5)).eval()
```